# Force exception when testing if hashlib is supported

Tags: python, unit-testing, try-catch, except, hashlib

So got stuck when trying to understand how I can force my test to go to throw a exception in this case. I have a function just testing if the library hashlib is supported or not when running on a machine.

```
def md5_is_supported():
    """Function to check if MD5 is supported
    Args:
        None
    Returns:
        bool: True if MD5 is supported, False otherwise
    """
    try:
        hashlib.md5()
        return True 
    except:
        return False
```

Now I want to build a test that goes into the except all the times, not just depending on if it is actually supporting hashlib or not.
How can I do that?

The test looks something like this right now:

```
def test_if_md5_is_supported():
    """Test to verify if md5 is supported or not"""
    assert integrity_check.md5_is_supported()
```

Comment: Can't you just replace `hashlib.md5` with a function of your own which raises the required exception? Use a mocking library, or simply manipulate the imported function directly from your test code.

Comment: @tripleee not sure what you mean? How do I replace a function which I'm suppose to test?

Comment: `import foo; foo.bar = my_overriding_function`